mpirun runs serial jobs instead of parallel jobs
I have ubuntu 24.04. I have installed gfortran and mpich. Using mpirun produces serial jobs instead than parallel.
When compiling the file test.f90 by
mpif90 -o test test.f90

and running it by
mpirun -np 2 ./test

I get
Hello World from process:            0 of            1
Hello World from process:            0 of            1

That is, the two processes are running independently instead then in parallel.
The correct, expected outcome should be
Hello World from process:            0 of            2
Hello World from process:            1 of            2

The file test.f90 contains the following
PROGRAM hello_world_mpi
include 'mpif.h'

integer process_Rank, size_Of_Cluster, ierror

call MPI_INIT(ierror)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size_Of_Cluster, ierror)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, process_Rank, ierror)

print *, 'Hello World from process: ', process_Rank, 'of ', size_Of_Cluster

end program hello_world_mpi

Many thanks!

This question is similar to: MPI_Comm_size always returns 1 again. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Please confirm the version of the MPI library you are using and read the linked question. Try OpenMPI if MPICH does not work properly.
